# Stop an animation from auto-playing in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this animation that I applied to a table. I would like for it to take place each time I click on a link that will change the contents of the table but not instantly when I am loading the page.

```
.scale-up {
    animation: scale-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your html code?

Answer (score 0):

> First remove class `scale-up` after it use `addClass` or `toogleClass` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  $('table').addClass('scale-up');
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  $('table').addClass('scale-up');
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.scale-up {
    animation: scale-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click On Me! </a>
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>This is tr1td1</td><td>This is tr1td2</td><td>This is tr1td2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>This is tr2td1</td><td>This is tr2td2</td><td>This is tr2td2</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can use `toogleClass` also:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  $('table').toggleClass('scale-up');
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
  $('table').toggleClass('scale-up');
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.scale-up {
    animation: scale-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me Two times... </a>
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>This is tr1td1</td><td>This is tr1td2</td><td>This is tr1td2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>This is tr2td1</td><td>This is tr2td2</td><td>This is tr2td2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve that using either JavaScript or JQuery. The trick is to add a class on certain event. Here is an example

**JavaScript**

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
element.classList.add("scale-up");
```

**JQuery**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#myDiv").addClass("scale-up");
});
```

Read more about it at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is done in JQuery

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $('.item').removeClass('scale-up');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.item').addClass('scale-up');
  }, 100)  
})
```

```css
.scale-up {
    animation: scale-up 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) both;
}

@keyframes scale-up {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='item'>Content</div>
<a class='link' href='#'>Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with JQuery - after adding the class, you will also need to remove it after the animation is complete to ensure it can be toggled on subsequent clicks. I've done this with a 500ms timeout in the example below:

```js
(function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("table");

  function addAnim() {
    c.classList.add("scale-up");

    setTimeout(function() {
      c.classList.remove("scale-up");
    }, 500);
  }

  c.addEventListener("click", addAnim);
})();
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjbpMb?editors=1111)